# Informatica DVO for value comparison

Tags: validation, informatica

I am comparing values from source to target using informatica dvo tool.  Its not giving desired results when comparing duplicate keys with different values. They pop up in the results as shown below ideally they should not.

```
Key A   Result A  Key B         Result B

000822  Managed   000822    Primary

000822  Primary   000822    Managed
```

Expected Result:

```
Key A   Result A  Key B     Result B
```

Answer (score 0):

The `000822` indicated as a key for comparison seems to be not unique. That results in creating cross join that multiplies the rows to:

```
Key A   Result A  Key B     Result B
------------------------------------
000822  Primary   000822    Primary <
000822  Managed   000822    Managed <
000822  Managed   000822    Primary
000822  Primary   000822    Managed
```

Next, the two first ones (indicated with <) are eliminated as identical. And the differences are reported.

You need to think of a better way for comparison. Perhaps you can use both columns (Key and Result)? It would solve this case.